# Google Play reported app crash but did not point out where

Tags: android, crash, google-play, release, google-play-console

Yesterday I uploaded my aab file to google play for a open testing. Google Play did report some app crashes in my app but it was not really clear, like below:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.boss.theblockhousev2, PID: 25729
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
    at g.c.a.j.a.h.g.b(:7)
    at m.b.run(:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Detected on 1 device during testing:
Nokia Nokia 1
480x854
Android 8.1 (SDK 27)
1,024 MB
ARM_V7
en_US

How can I find my bug now? Please help.
Thank you guys a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Firebase Crashlytics` for that. It will tell you all the information like:-

- Line of Code where the crash happened.
- Exception
- On Which Device
  the crash occured, etc.